# How to start a python-daemon over ssh connection?

Tags: python, ssh, daemon, paramiko, python-daemon

I want to log into a remote computer using the python library paramiko,
then start a daemon process using the python-daemon library which, after 
the programm terminates, is still working as some kind of job queue.
This is my code so far:
(in this example the daemon will just open a file and print some random numbers into it)

```
#client.py
import paramiko

def main():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect('machine1', username='user1')

    command = 'python server_daemon.py'

    stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
    ssh.close()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

'

```
#server_daemon.py
import time
import daemon

def main():
    with daemon.DaemonContext():
        s = [str(x)+"\n" for x in range(1000)]
        for i in s:
            with open("test.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(i)
                time.sleep(0.4)

        while True:
            pass

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to do the thing,
if I remove the daemonizing context from the script it seems to work but I have to wait for the server to finish.
I also tried to redirect the output to `/dev/null` and this didn't work,
thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Does it help to change command to 'nohup python server_daemon.py' ?

Comment: tried this one , also with screen but somehow both options didn't work out.

Comment: What exactly does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: Well no daemon process is started, at least i can't see any file output.